# unrecognized selector sent to instance, reason

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, exception

Whenever I call

```
self.gLViewController = [[GLViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GLViewController" bundle:nil];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.gLViewController animated:YES];
```

I get the following error:

```
2012-06-06 15:22:50.329 NavApp[5357:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MiniGamesViewController setGLViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f6aa730'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x353b788f 0x3775e259 0x353baa9b 0x353b9915 0x35314650 0xb14cf 0x353113fd 0x32e06e07 0x32e06dc3 0x32e06da1 0x32e06b11 0x32e07449 0x32e0592b 0x32e05319 0x32deb695 0x32deaf3b 0x36faa22b 0x3538b523 0x3538b4c5 0x3538a313 0x3530d4a5 0x3530d36d 0x36fa9439 0x32e19cd5 0xaeae5 0x60ce4)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Can anyone help tell me exactly what this is saying? I have been working at this for a solid hour and am getting nowhere. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: In GLViewController if you are using  interface builder, make sure that the View of GLViewController is linked to the file owner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to synthesize the property
in your `MiniGamesViewController`.m

```
//After the implementation
@implementation MiniGamesViewController
//Add this line
@synthesize gLViewController;
```

Comment: EDIT: Look's like I forgot that... adding now.

Comment: well it happens more than you may think :), please dont forget to upvote and/or accept the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: The compiler should have warned you if you didn't provide an implementation for the declared property, either by manually defining the accessors, by `@synthesize`, or by `@dynamic`. You might want to set the build setting which promotes warnings to errors.